# Import Existing Django Application into Pycharm

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I have an existing Django application. I want to start developing it in Pycharm, instead of sublime text and command line. I have opened my existing directory (cloned from my git repo) into Pycharm but I can not for the life of me figure out how to set it as a django project. All the examples I see are new projects from scratch or existing pycharm projects, neither of which applies to me. I'm running on a brand new mac, if that helps (I'm coming from Ubuntu)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to enable [`Django Support`](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/django-support.html) in the [project settings](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/configuring-project-settings.html) under `Project Settings -> Django`. You also would need to set up the project root, path to `settings.py` and `manage.py`.

Comment: So this might be where I am messing up. I opened Pycharm and then opened the directory of my existing django application. I don't actually see a project settings dialog. Do I need to do something to make this a project? Apologies if I am being obtuse here.

Comment: @Feasoron yup, open `Preferences`, then select `Django` under `Project Settings`.

Comment: I picked your answer as right, which it is. However, in case anyone else winds up here, I had accidentally downloaded the community edition, not the 30 day trial, so I didn't have version with Django support.

Comment: @Feasoron my bad, should have noted this. Thanks for sharing!